# Is it possible to install apache-superset in cpanel?

Tags: python, cpanel, apache-superset

i wanted to try installing apache superset in cpanel. However, there are no guides or documentation about it (maybe i just didnt found it / read carefully). If there any clues, it would be helpful for me. I have no experience in using cpanel.

i did `pip install apache-superset` and it was successful. However, when i tried to do `superset db upgrade` the result is: (the openblas blas thread init: pthread_create failed for thread 39 of 40: Resource temporarily unavailable, its started from 6 of 40 to 39 of 40

```
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC -1 current, -1 max
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 39 of 40: Resource temporarily unavailable
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC -1 current, -1 max
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user1/virtualenv/venv/3.11/bin/superset", line 5, in <module>
    from superset.cli.main import superset
  File "/home/user1/virtualenv/venv/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/superset/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from superset.app import create_app
  File "/home/user1/virtualenv/venv/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/superset/app.py", line 23, in <module>
    from superset.initialization import SupersetAppInitializer
  File "/home/user1/virtualenv/venv/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/superset/initialization/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from superset.extensions import (
  File "/home/user1/virtualenv/venv/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/superset/extensions/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from superset.utils.async_query_manager import AsyncQueryManager
  File "/home/user1/virtualenv/venv/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/superset/utils/async_query_manager.py", line 26, in <module>
    from superset.utils.core import get_user_id
  File "/home/user1/virtualenv/venv/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/superset/utils/core.py", line 58, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/home/user1/virtualenv/venv/3.11/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/home/user1/virtualenv/venv/3.11/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/home/user1/virtualenv/venv/3.11/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py",line 10, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/home/user1/virtualenv/venv/3.11/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 6, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
KeyboardInterrupt
```